# How to specify the city in the url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, routeparams

There are multiple urls

```
Route::get('part/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\PartsController::class, 'part'])->name('part');
Route::get('parts', [App\Http\Controllers\PartsController::class, 'parts'])->name('parts');
Route::get('spare-cars/{marka?}/{model?}/{slug?}', [App\Http\Controllers\CarController::class, 'spareCars'])->name('spare.cars');
```

I need to specify the city in front of each url, for example

`site.ru/ekaterinburg/part` - cities are indicated dynamically, while it is necessary in the absence of a city, substitute it automatically, for example

We go to the address `site.ru/part` - redirect to the default value of the city - `site.ru/moskva/part` and similarly with other addresses

How can this be done?

**Answer**

Thanks @shaedrich

Added all routes to the group and added processing of calls to links without cities

```
Route::prefix('{city?}')->group(function() {
    Route::get('part/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\PartsController::class, 'part'])->name('part');
    Route::get('parts', [App\Http\Controllers\PartsController::class, 'parts'])->name('parts');
    Route::get('spare-cars/{marka?}/{model?}/{slug?}', [App\Http\Controllers\CarController::class, 'spareCars'])->name('spare.cars');
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\PartsController::class, 'checkUrl'])->name('checkUrl');
});


    public function checkUrl($slug) {
        if($slug == 'parts') {
            return redirect('moskva/parts');
        } else if($slug == 'part') {
            return redirect('moskva/part');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [route group](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups) with a [route prefix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes):

```
Route::prefix('{city?}')->group(function() {
    Route::get('part/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\PartsController::class, 'part'])->name('part');
    Route::get('parts', [App\Http\Controllers\PartsController::class, 'parts'])->name('parts');
    Route::get('spare-cars/{marka?}/{model?}/{slug?}', [App\Http\Controllers\CarController::class, 'spareCars'])->name('spare.cars');
});
```

If you need the city parameter always to be present even if it's not in the URL, you can pass a default value to the controller action like so:

```
class PartsController extends Controller
{
    public function part($citry = 'moskva', $slug)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I supplemented the answer with my solution, according to your answer

Comment: You're welcome. I've also updated my answer so it might help you with an optional default value.